# Python dictionary with lists: get key of a list which contains max value at specific index

Tags: python, list, dictionary, max

I have a dictionary with lists as values like:

```
data = {'key1': ['a', 2, 3], 'key2': ['b', 1, 2], 'key3': ['c', 3, 1]}
```

Now I want to get the key of the list which contains the max value at a specific index, e.g. [1].

I get the max value like this:

```
maxValue = max(data[key][1] for key in data)
```

which gives me 3 as output.

How can I get the corresponding key? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Not only possible, but even very easy:

```
max((data[key][1],key) for key in data)
```

returns:

```
(3, 'key3')
```

You can insert this into variables like this:

```
maxValue, keyMaxValue = max((data[key][1],key) for key in data)
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this:

```
data = {'key1': ['a', 2, 5, 3], 'key2': ['b', 1, 9], 'key3': ['c', 3, 1]}

maxValueList=[]
for key in data:
    maxValueList.append({key:max(data[key][1:])})

print(maxValueList)
```

output:

```
[{'key1': 5}, {'key2': 9}, {'key3': 3}]
```

Comment: sorry missed that:
contains the max value at a specific index

Answer (score 0):

A bit more not so straightforward approach :

Filter the dict to have values of first index, sort it by values in reverse and output the tuples.

```
sorted({k:v[1] for k,v in data.items()}.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)

[('key3', 3), ('key1', 2), ('key2', 1)]
```

Then extract the first element which is the max.